# BeautifulSoup - don't crawl tag if in certain div class

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I need to crawl plain text from around ~2000 websites which don't have a common page structure and probably makes it hard to crawl with one script, I think.

So as a 'first time crawler' I did a couple of try and errors with BeautifulSoup. Currently I managed to crawl some plain text by looking at the content between certain tags (<p> and all the heading tags) with the following:

```
soup.findAll(['p', re.compile('h[0-9]'), 'title'])
```

However, sometimes there's some rss/news-feed from which I don't want to have the text. From what I saw in the source code of the pages, it is surrounded by a css div-class. So my question would be if I can tell the above command not to crawl the text if it's surrounded by a certain div-class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function as a filter:

```
`def my_filter(tag):
return (tag.name == 'p' or re.compile('h[0-9]').match(tag.name) or tag.name== 'title') and (tag.parent['class'] != 'certain_div_class' or not tag.parent.has_attr('class')) 

my_tags = soup.findAll(my_filter)`
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code is not working for some reason. If I copy&paste it, it's not working at all because of this part:

`(tag.parent['class'] != 'certain_div_class' or not tag.parent.has_attr('class')`

But still, when I remove this part, I don't get the output that I want and that I got with my code from above. I think your code is not filtering out the text surrounded by the heading tags. This maybe needs another approach then? Not sure...

Comment: I've missed the closing bracket in that long expression, sorry for that. Edited the code now. And don't forget to change 'certain_div_class' to the proper class name.

Comment: No problem about the bracket but that's what I already took account for when trying it out. And I also filled out the desired class. The actual problem is rather the regex-expression which doesn't work with you approach. When I hard-type the heading tags, i.e. 'h1' then I get the output with the my previous output. Do you might have any idea how I could make that work in a nice way without typing 'h1' or 'h2' and so on...?

Comment: Yep, right, we both used `re` in a wrong way. There should be `re.compile('h[0-9]').match(tag.name)` instead of `tag.name == re.compile(...)` I also would make it `^h[0-9]{1}` as a precise regex.